# JavaMelody - Monitoring Free Disk Space in JSON or XML

Tags: java, java-melody

I am using Tomcat and Javamelody and need the "Free Disk Space" of the machine. In the normal web view there is a table row for that, but in XML or JSON output (format=xml) this value is missing ?! Is this is bug?  How can i get the free disk space without modifying my java app ?

Answer (score 0):

Si, the free disk space is in the xml/json.

You can find it in the response of the http requests:

.../monitoring?format=xml&part=jvm
or
.../monitoring?format=json&part=jvm

Or you can just get the last value in the free disk space graph, without other data:

.../monitoring?part=lastValue&graph=Free_disk_space

For reference:

https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/ExternalAPI